# Highlighting a slice in Google Visualization Pie chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

How can I select a slice in the pie chart so that it would have the hovered (highlighted) effect? Is it supported? `setSelection` doesn't seem to work in this manner:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(element);
chart.draw(dataTable, options);

...
chart.setSelection({row: rowIdx});
```

Answer (score 5):

The selection is an array of objects, not a single object, so you need to set it like this:

```
chart.setSelection([{row: rowIdx}]);
```